# asynchronous commenting using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a comment system on my website where the user can comment & see it appear on the page without reloading the page, kind of like how you post a comment on facebook and see it appear right away. I'm having trouble with this however as my implementation shows the comment the user inputs, but then erases the previous comments that were already on the page (as any comments section, I'd want the user to comment and simply add on to the previous comments). Also, when the user comments, the page reloads, and displays the comment in the text box, rather than below the text box where the comments are supposed to be displayed. I've attached the code. Index.php runs the ajax script to perform the asynchronous commenting, and uses the form to get the user input which is dealt with in insert.php. It also prints out the comments stored in a database.

index.php

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submitButton').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "insert.php",
                data : { field1_name : $('#userInput').val() },
                beforeSend: function(){
                }
                , complete: function(){
                }
                , success: function(html){
                    $("#comment_part").html(html);
                    window.location.reload();

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<form id="comment_form" action="insert.php" method="GET">
    Comments:
    <input type="text" class="text_cmt" name="field1_name" id="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id = "submitButton"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
</form>
```

```
 <div id='comment_part'>
 <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', '', 'comment_schema');
    $query="SELECT COMMENTS FROM csAirComment";
    $results = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo '<div class="comment" >';
        $output= $row["COMMENTS"];
        //protects against cross site scripting
        echo htmlspecialchars($output ,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
  </div>
```

insert.php

```
$userInput= $_GET["field1_name"];
if(!empty($userInput)) {
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $userInput);
    $field1_name_array = explode(" ",$field1_name);

    foreach($field1_name_array as $element){
        $query = "SELECT replaceWord FROM changeWord WHERE badWord = '" . $element . "' ";
        $query_link = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_link)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_link);
            $goodWord = $row['replaceWord'];
            $element= $goodWord;
        }
        $newComment = $newComment." ".$element;
    }

    //Escape user inputs for security
    $sql = "INSERT INTO csAirComment (COMMENTS) VALUES ('$newComment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    //attempt insert query execution

    //header("Location:csair.php");
    die();

    mysqli_close($link);
}
else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
}
```

The insert.php takes in the user input and then inserts it into the database (by first filtering and checking for bad words). Just not sure where I'm going wrong, been stuck on it for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 main problems in your code:

1. You are not returning anything from `insert.php` via ajax.
2. You don't need to replace the whole `comment_part`, just add the new comment to it.
3. Why are you reloading the page? I thought that the whole purpose of using Ajax was to have a dynamic content.

In your ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "insert.php",
            data : { field1_name : $('#userInput').val() },
            beforeSend: function(){
            }
            , complete: function(){
            }
            , success: function(html){
                //this will add the new comment to the `comment_part` div
                $("#comment_part").append(html);
            }
        });
```

Within `insert.php` you need to return the new comment html:

```
$userInput= $_GET["field1_name"];
if(!empty($userInput)) {
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $userInput);
    $field1_name_array = explode(" ",$field1_name);

    foreach($field1_name_array as $element){
        $query = "SELECT replaceWord FROM changeWord WHERE badWord = '" . $element . "' ";
        $query_link = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_link)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_link);
            $goodWord = $row['replaceWord'];
            $element= $goodWord;
        }
        $newComment = $newComment." ".$element;
    }

    //Escape user inputs for security
    $sql = "INSERT INTO csAirComment (COMMENTS) VALUES ('$newComment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    //attempt insert query execution

    mysqli_close($link);

    //here you need to build your new comment html and return it
    return "<div class='comment'>...the new comment html...</div>";
}
else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
}
```

Please note that you currently don't have any error handling, so when you return `die('comment is not set....')` it will be displayed as well as a new comment.
You can return a better structured response using `json_encode()` but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: What I'm confused about is what I'm returning in the insert.php file and what my div id="comment_part" will contain. So in the insert.php am I simply returning what I've originally written in the div id="comment_part"? Basically the stuff with the echoing from the database?

Comment: @OviyaArasu you want to return only the new comment's html and APPEND it to the existing div, not replace everything. When you use `html()` you are replacing, when you use `append()` you are adding the html to the end of the div.

Comment: What do you mean by return the new comment's html? As in what the content is (the data from the database) or the formatting? I'm just not exactly sure of what I'm supposed to return in the comment's html.

Comment: @OviyaArasu return a string (written in my answer) - i.e when you return "<div><div>" and then use jQuery `append()` it will automatically take that string and add it to the page as an html element.

Comment: ok so then in my index.php, where I have the stuff within my div id=comment_part, I don't need all of that right? Because the insert.php is taking care of inserting it as an html element?

Comment: @OviyaArasu no, what you have in `index.php` will render existing comments when the page loads, when a new comment is added, you ajax will add it to the database and then you can use `append` to add it to the page without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: thanks, but it's still not working. do you think there's something wrong in the append?

Comment: use the console and see if you have errors, also do `console.log(html)` and see what it gives you. You need to debug it from this point on since this should work. Is you ajax working correctly? what does the developer tools show you?

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery.html() which is replacing everything in your element with your "html" contents. Try using jQuery.append() instead.

Comment: i've changed it to append, however it's still not working. do you think there's something incorrect with how i've used append? I've changed my code to what another commenter, Yani, posted. His corrections seem to make sense but I think something is wrong with append, not sure.

Comment: Change your posted code above to reflect the changes you've made so that we can see what's different and go from there.